# jQuery date picker multi select and unselect

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is it possible to enable jquery UI (datepicker) to enable multi select and unselect ?

example of datepicker i am using. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

i have got a requirement as to enable a datepicker to select multiple dates and i am wondering how to implement a similar one. 
Your prompt reply is greatly appreciated.
Please give me some examples
Thanks

Comment: May this forum gives you some idea. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-pick-multiple-dates

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**Multidatespickr**](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/) is a little plugin that enables jQuery UI calendar to manage multiple dates.

**Features:**

- Select date ranges.
- Pick multiple dates not in secuence.
- Define a maximum number of pickable dates.
- Define a range X days from where it is possible to select Y dates.
- Define unavailable dates.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
<script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"/>

<input id="datePick" type="text"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

OR

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbk3bwd1/).

Comment: Hi, tnx for this, but how would it be possible to change the selected dates highlight color. currently it does show an evry light yellow color which is not pretty enough highlighted...  then is it possible to display the datepick inline ? (without clicking the textbox, it should just load and be in the same position). please let me know.

Comment: Yes it is possible to change the selected date color.  Let me try and let you know.   It is simple to show in inline check this http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/1/

Comment: JS fiddle is not working please fix

Comment: JS fiddle is not working please fix

Comment: @AmanDeep http://jsfiddle.net/xbk3bwd1/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=xbk3bwd1

Comment: Thank you @Praveen

Comment: Why when we select the past month dates , it automatically comes to the current month?

Comment: @Praveen if you please let me know how I can use multidatepicker for date range with onSelect event.

Answer (score 3):

The following link might be of some help to you.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
[Kendo UI Calender](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/calendar/index.html)
Kendo UI is an implementation of javascript.