# MultiDatesPicker v1.6.4 for jQuery UI replace text field with dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

Hi there i used the above mentioned js file and other jquery ui files to select multiple dates. As i saw in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651766/jquery-date-picker-multi-select-and-unselect) the selected dates are seperated by comma in the text field but in my case it is replacing the dates with the newly selecting dates.
I just did this.

```
   $(document).ready(function(}{
   $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have researched some blogs and queries posted by others and i have end up with the conclusion that this issue may be due the conflict in validation.By the way i am trying to use this multiple datepicker functionality in magento.

So i used another multiple datepicker which is quite good and fulfills my requirement [keith-wood.name](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML)

I am posting this answer so that it may help other.